# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() when converting list of tuples to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of tuples like this

```
tmp
[('chr19', 50003781, '+', 5303232448),
 ('chr19', 58856544, '+', 5303232448),
 ('chr19', 58856544, '+', 5303232448),
 ('chr10', 52559169, '+', 12460988980),
...]
```

and I have been following many answers from StackOverflow to convert this into a pandas data frame. Basically I need this

```
col1    col2      col3     col4
chr19   50003781.  +     5303232448
```

When I tried to do that with for example this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3","col4])
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means, `tmp` is not a list of tuples, there is an integer in it.

For example,

```
tmp = [('chr19', 50003781, '+', 5303232448),
 ('chr19', 58856544, '+', 5303232448),
 ('chr19', 58856544, '+', 5303232448),
 ('chr10', 52559169, '+', 12460988980), 1]
```

will give the same error. See if

```
any(isinstance(t, int) for t in tmp)
```

is True or not. If True it means there is an integer value in `tmp`. In that case, you probably want to filter it out when passing `tmp` to the DataFrame constructor.